# How do I change my query based on user input via checkboxes?

Tags: c#, if-statement

Here's my code:

```
var query = from x in Data

select new { Fruit = x[0], Animal, x[2], Color = x[3], Food = x[4] };
```

Now, I want to create checkboxes such that if a user checks off "box 1" it will do a different query like so:

```
select new { Fruit = x[7], Animal, x[4], Color = x[8], Food = x[9] };
```

My question is, **how do I make it so that depending on which checkbox is checked a different `select...new` statement will be used**?

I think I can use multiple if/then statements to see which particular box is checked and to determine which `select...new` statement to use, but I'm guessing there is a better way out there.

In VB I think a "case" statement would come into play, but I don't know what is the C# equivalent.

My failed attempt at implementing case/switch in the context of changing query parameters:

```
int caseSwitch = 1;
var query = from x in Data

switch (caseSwitch)
{

       case 1:
           select new { Fruit = x[0], Animal, x[2], Color = x[3], Food = x[4] };
           break;

       case 2:
           select new { Fruit = x[7], Animal, x[4], Color = x[8], Food = x[9] };
           break;
}
```

Comment: the C# equivalent is the [switch statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: Ok I see switch/case..but how do I implement it in the context of a query?  I tried putting switch(caseSwitch) { case 1: <insert select new code>; break; }, but I don't think I'm doing it right.

Comment: Why not put the whole query inside the switch statement?

Comment: UGH, you're right.  I don't see why not either.

Comment: isn't there a formula you could use to calculate the indexes of the array you want based on the input of the checkboxes?

Comment: well, i just realized "var query = from x in Data" will appear multiple times in my code.  one time for each case.  is this a bad thing?

Comment: duplicate code is considered 'a bad thing'

Comment: The declare the variable once and then initialize it once in the switch statement. Duplicate code is sometimes necessary (not saying it is in this case), but I believe that the general view of duplicate code as "bad" is in cases when you have longer segments of code that is just copied and pasted.

Though, suppose you would like to change the variable name in this case; declaring it outside the switch block would only require one change of code instead of n changes (n = number of cases).

Comment: Whats the logic behind determining your indexes? You could reduce the duplicate code if there is logic for determining the indexes instead of just having them hardcoded for each situation...

Comment: duplicate code is never 'necessary', but solving the problem with other options might be considered 'over engineering'. If your goal here to understand the if/switch statement structure and syntax of C#, duplicate code is not bad. Trying to make a piece of software which will be more flexible and maintainable duplicate code is bad, there are plenty other options (Patterns) that can solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to vary your query you can use a `switch` statement.  However, in doing so you cannot use anonymous types.  You will need to define a object that you can use, so the query object can be defined when declared.

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Fruit { get; set; }
    public string Animal { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public string Food { get; set; }
}

IEnumerable<Foo> query = null;
switch (caseSwitch)
{
    case 1:
        query = from x in Data
                select new Foo { Fruit = x[0], Animal = x[2], Color = x[3], 
                    Food = x[4] };
         break;

     case 2:
         query = from x in Data
                select new Foo { Fruit = x[7], Animal = x[4], Color = x[8],
                    Food = x[9] };
         break;

     default:
         // handle however you need to
}
```

You can also inline it entirely into your LINQ query, however, if you extending the code for multiple cases will make the code more difficult to understand and maintain.

```
var query = from x in Data
            // needed to get the caseSwitch value into context in the select
            //  otherwise it is considered out of context
            let sw = caseSwitch  
            select sw == 1 ?
                new { Fruit = x[0], Animal = x[2], Color = x[3], Food = x[4] } :
                new { Fruit = x[7], Animal = x[4], Color = x[8], Food = x[9] }
```

The issue with this approach is when the `caseSwitch` is outside the valid range of values you may get a value you did not want.  This is better handled by using a `switch` statement, where you can set the query to a default value or throw an exception when the `default` case is reached.

Example of how the inlined LINQ with more than two cases

```
var query = from x in Data
            let sw = caseSwitch  
            select 
                sw == 1 ? new { Fruit = x[0], Animal = x[2], Color = x[3], Food = x[4] }
                : sw == 2 ? new { Fruit = x[7], Animal = x[4], Color = x[8], Food = x[9] }
                : sw == 3 ? new { Fruit = x[10], Animal = x[11], Color = x[12], Food = x[13] }
                : null; // final value is the default value
```

Answer (score 1):

You could factor out the select item into a function:

```
function object getItem(DataItem x, int caseSwitch)
{
    switch (caseSwitch)
    {
       case 1:
           return new { Fruit = x[0], Animal, x[2], Color = x[3], Food = x[4] };
           break;
       case 2:
           return new { Fruit = x[7], Animal, x[4], Color = x[8], Food = x[9] };
           break;
    }
}
```

And then you can do the following query:

```
int caseSwitch = 1;
var query = from x in Data
            select getItem(x, caseSwitch);
```